# Does PayPal calculate taxes thru express checkout?

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment, payment-processing

PayPal stores Billing And Shipping addresses for express checkout action.
Can PayPal manually calculate taxes thru express checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Express Checkout requires you to calculate and send the taxes to us.
Express Checkout won't be able to do this for you (the tax calculator you might've seen on your profile will also not apply to Express Checkout transactions).

Comment: Finally a straight answer. However, this is a feature I really wanted for express. Now I have to ask the customer if they feel like paying tax or not.